# edit my centos 6 network config file using PHP code but after network restart i get an error

Tags: php, networking, centos, static-ip-address

I am using a simple file operation on the PHP in order to edit the config file for network interface on CentOS 6.7(/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
), after change in any value and save into the config file and try to restart the network interface i get this error:

```
does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
[FAILED]
```

my PHP code is this:

```
<?php

// configuration
$file = '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0';

// check if form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['text']))
{
// save the text contents
file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text']);

// redirect to form again
header('Location: network.php');
exit();
}

// read the textfile
$text = file_get_contents($file);

?>
<!-- HTML form -->
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea style="width:50%; height:50%;" name="text"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text) ?></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
<input type="reset" />
</form>
```

i need manually called the network script by command setup and do a modification in the device setting and save then i will be able to restart the network interface. appreciate if anyone help me why this issue happen while if i open the config file and edit it manually it wouldn't cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that the user name the server runs as (by default `apache` on most Red Hat-based distributions) doesn't have permission to write to`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

You should check the return values of:

```
file_put_contents($file, $_POST['text']);
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

> This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

---

I presume this script will only be run by your or trusted colleagues given that there's no validation of the user input. Indentation would also make the PHP code more readable.

Comment: actually now the issue is not the permission as i change the file permission temporary and i can see the content of the file update successfully the only issue is after make change using this php file when try to restart the network service i get the error and till i don't run the setup command and made some modification in the device setting i am not able to bring up my network interface. regarding the security matter at this stage your correct but after i be able to get it work properly i will add the user validity as well.